# How do I add an extension to a parameter in oak/deno?

Tags: deno, oak

I'm trying to add `.rss` to the end of a parameterized url:

```
  .get(
    "/searches/history/tags/:tag.rss",
    controller.getHistoryByTagRss.bind(controller)
  )
```

I need a way to isolate the `:tag` from the `.rss`

Currently this isn't working.

Comment: What version of Deno/Oak are you using? doing GET `/tags/foo.rss` works for me with `ctx.params.tag` being `foo`

Comment: I'm using Oak v.12.6.0 give me `html.rss` for tag.

Comment: What OS and Deno version? Might be related to that.

Comment: i had to move the `:tag.rss` route above the `:tag` route.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by upgrading oak to latest version and moving route above default route.